# In Django REST Framework, how to filter list based on user?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models, User and Book. Users own books and can only be seen by their owners.

NOTE: the book model is handled in a separate database, so I can't use a foreign key on Book pointing to User. Not sure if this matters.

If I'm authenticated, and send a `GET /books` request, I want only the books owned by the user to be shown. If I'm not authenticated, I should get a 403 error.

Where should I implement this logic?

I could do it in the View, with something like this:

```
class BookView(APIView):
    """
    Get books
    """
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsBookOwner,)
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        # create a book

    def get(self, request):
        books = Book.objects.filter(owner_id=request.user.owner_id)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(books, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

```
class IsBookOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Object-level permission to only allow seeing his own books
    """

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):

        # obj here is a Book instance
        return obj.owner_id == request.user.owner_id
```

Is this the correct way to do it? Also, is the IsBookOwner permission doing anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User model dont have owner_id field. You should change request.user.owner_id to request.user.id

For get request you dont need IsBookOwner Permission. You already check owner in your queryset. if you need to check book owner entire view, it is okay.

```
books = Book.objects.filter(owner_id=request.user.owner_id)
```

Comment: I did define user.owner_id in my model as the pk, so it is valid. Thanks for the response!